# how to manage documentation of past events (add files, links, summary, etc)

Tags: civievent, documentation

so we are using civicrm for events, webinars etc. we want to move the documentation of the events also to civicrm (photos, presentations, attendees, summary, links etc.)
for contacts its easy with the activities tabs. is there a way to link activities to (past) events. or do you know a way how to do documentation for events in civicrm?
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom data/fields for Events and can attached the documentation.

**Custom fields for events**

[image: Custom Fields for Events]

**Attach the files when you configure events**

[image: Attach the files when you configure event]

**Download documentation from Event info page**

[image: Download documentation from Event info page]

Comment: thanks. thats the same idea i came up with. the only problem i see that i cant add multiple files. but i will do it that way. do you know if i can export the documentation and it will export the files and not the files as a path?

Comment: Did you mean download the documention?

Comment: yes. lets say at the end of the year we want to download all the documentations of the events we had in the year to make a final report. do i need to go to every event and download ever photo, presentation manually or can i download everything in one (for one event)

Comment: You will need to download photos, presentations, etc manually by clicking each file. SUGGESTION (Not tested): If you are using Drupal, you can create a View to list all events for the year with the custom data (file fields) exposed, so that you have the list of events and all the files in the same view, which makes it easy to download.

Comment: well thanks! ill keep you posted who i will manage the downloads, and yes we are using drupal